# Создание блока на JS и прикрепить к нему ссылку на контроллер MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, controller

Мне нужно создать новый блок на сайте, и при его нажатии он будет обрабатываться контроллером Card

**JS Script:**

```
    loadBtn.onclick = function () {    let card = document.createElement("a");
    let cardName = document.createElement("p");
    card.className = "card";    card.id = "card" + count;
    card.setAttribute("asp-controller", "Card");    card.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    cardLine1.prepend(card);    cardName = 'Звонок ' + count;
    card.prepend(cardName);
    count++;
```

**Html-шаблон по которому должно создаваться карточка по скрипту:**

```
<div id="line1" class="lines line1"> <!-- Ряд 1 --> 
   <a asp-controller="Card" target="_blank" id="line1_card" class="card"> 
     <p>Звонок 1</p> 
     <p>@_responseHelper.GetApiResponse().call_date</p> 
     <p>@_responseHelper.GetApiResponse().operator_fio</p> 
   </a> 
 </div>
```

**Контроллер Card:**

```
public class CardController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
            return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: И? Что не получается? Вы не задали вопрос. / `asp-controller` - это Anchor Tag Helper. Посмотрите, какой HTML генерируется в итоге: [asp-controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-8.0#asp-controller)